# Array appears to evaluate to empty after filling from HTTP GET request

Tags: arrays, angular, ag-grid

I'm calling a HTTP GET to an API which gets back weather data, to display to an ag-grid table. The code, below:

```
getWeatherData(date?:Date){

    let array_table_rowData = new Array();
    let dte1 = new Date();
    if(date){
      dte1 = date;
    }
    dte1.setDate(dte1.getDate() - 28);
    let dte2 = dte1.setDate(dte1.getDate() + 4);
    let dte3 = dte1.setDate(dte1.getDate() + 4);
    let dte4 = dte1.setDate(dte1.getDate() + 4);
    let dte5 = dte1.setDate(dte1.getDate() + 4);
    let dte6 = dte1.setDate(dte1.getDate() + 4);
    let dte7 = dte1.setDate(dte1.getDate() + 4);

    let url_dte1 = this.url_getWeatherData + "?date=" + this.datePipe.transform(dte1, "yyyy-MM-dd");    
    let url_dte2 = this.url_getWeatherData + "?date=" + this.datePipe.transform(dte2, "yyyy-MM-dd");    
    let url_dte3 = this.url_getWeatherData + "?date=" + this.datePipe.transform(dte3, "yyyy-MM-dd");    
    let url_dte4 = this.url_getWeatherData + "?date=" + this.datePipe.transform(dte4, "yyyy-MM-dd");    
    let url_dte5 = this.url_getWeatherData + "?date=" + this.datePipe.transform(dte5, "yyyy-MM-dd");    
    let url_dte6 = this.url_getWeatherData + "?date=" + this.datePipe.transform(dte6, "yyyy-MM-dd");    
    let url_dte7 = this.url_getWeatherData + "?date=" + this.datePipe.transform(dte7, "yyyy-MM-dd");
    let array_url = [url_dte1,url_dte2,url_dte3,url_dte4,url_dte5,url_dte6,url_dte7];

    for(let i=0; i < array_url.length; i++){

        this.http.get(array_url[i]).subscribe(data => {

            let forecasts_pull = data.items[0].forecasts;
            for(let j=0; j < forecasts_pull.length; j++){
              let forecast = forecasts_pull[j]
              console.log(array_url[i]);
              this.array_rowData.push(
                {
                  date:forecast.date,
                  //tempHigh:forecast.temperature.high,
                  //tempLow:forecast.temperature.low,
                  //humiHigh:forecast.relative_humidity.high,
                  //humiLow:forecast.relative_humidity.low
                });
            }

        });
    }
  }

  async onGridReady(params){
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

    await this.getWeatherData();

    console.log(this.table_rowData);

    console.log(this.array_rowData);

    this.array_rowData.forEach(forecast =>{
      console.log(forecast)
    });

    this.gridApi.setRowData(this.table_rowData);
  }
}
```

This calls the API just fine, but ag-grid is unable to detect that there are objects in the array. When I checked the console.log to compare a hardcoded array (table_rowData) versus getWeatherData's array, I find this:

[non-empty array vs apparent empty array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoNAd.png)

I know one of the problems might be that when ag-grid finishes loading and evaluating, the array they're supposed to read from still appears to be empty. However, running `setRowData` after `await getWeatherData` yields the same result. Is there any wait to force ag-grid to wait until after the arrays finish evaluating? I have a feeling it has something to do with the way I chose to GET the data.

Appreciate any advice you guys can give!

Comment: Of course `ag-grid` doesn't know about the row data, because at the time you are calling `setRowData()` the rows array is empty. You need to wait for all the `GET` requests, and after that you need to call `setRowData()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ag-grid` can't know about the changes of the array. You need refactor your code, so you will call `setRowData()` after all `HTTP` requests are completed. Here's the example, how you could do that.

```js
...
getWeatherData(date?:Date) {
    ...

    // create array of http urls
    const array_url: Array<string> = [...];

    // create array of observables
    const observableArray: Array<Observable<any>> = array_url.map((url) => this.http.get(url));

    // merge all observables into one
    forkJoin(subsArray).subscribe((data: Array<any>) => {

        // process every http response
        data.foreEach((response: any) => {
            const forecasts_pull = response.items[0].forecasts;

            forecasts_pull.forEach((forecast: any) => {
                // push into the row data array
                this.array_rowData.push({
                    date: forecast.date,   
                })
            })
        })

        // after every response is processed, set the rowData
        this.gridApi.setRowData(this.array_rowData)
     }); 
   }

onGridReady(params: any) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
}
```

Comment: thank you, I was struggling with ensuring the updateRowData function was called after the GET calls, so I assume that await is not enough?